# R input redirection

Tags: r, input

Here is the way i use R:

I generally type R in my terminal, I enter the R console, and i use:

```
source("prog.R")
```

To execute my program and examine the results within the console.

Now, i need to read data from stdin so i did:

```
f <- file("stdin")
open(f)
while(length(line <- readLines(f,n=1)) > 0) {
  # process line
}
```

Now i have stored my input in input.txt and i need to redirect it to stdin, using source command within the console.

Like in c++

```
./a.out < input.txt
```

I need within the R console, something like

```
>source("prog.R) < input.txt
```

How can i do this?

Comment: You have a very strange workflow. Are you committed to it? Most of us use an IDE.

Comment: I am not commited to R i am just using it for a current project, so i do not want to get an IDE, and i use the console, so that i can examine the values, later after execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can absolutely write non-interactive R scripts. Just don’t launch them inside an interactive R shell. Instead, launch them on the command line like you would launch a C++ program, and put the following [shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) at the top of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
… rest of script
```

Then make your script executable on the command line:

```
chmod +x path/to/script
```

… and use it:

```
path/to/script < input.txt
```

Alternatively, you can do

```
Rscript path/to/script < input.txt
```

That way you don’t need the shebang line, nor do you need to make the script file executable.

By the way, you can use `stdin()` instead of `file('stdin')` in R.